a question about cluster points of a convex set
Suppose $X$ is a nonempty convex subset of $R^n$, $x$ is a cluster point of $X$ and $y$ is a boundary  of $X$. Is  there   a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$ ($y$) such that for all $n, x_n \notin  \bar{X} $, the closure of $X$, why?

Let $ S = \{x_n \} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and we're interested in seeing whether or not $S \cap \bar X$ is non-empty and/or contains only one element.
For every $n$ we have a neighbourhood $B_n$ s.t. $B_n$ does not intersect $\bar X$. Likewise take $x$ as a cluster point of $X$, it has neighbourhoods $U$, then there exists some $m$ s.t. $m \geq n$ and $x_m \in U$. This is to say there is an infinite amount of points in the sequence for the neighbourhood $U$which belong in it.
Because $x \in \bar X$, we have $U \cap \bar X \neq \emptyset$ for all $U$, and we have $x_m \in U$, so $S \cap \bar X \neq \emptyset$ and it contains more than one element.
Such a sequence does not exist.

thanks  very much, in fact, I do not understand what you say.  On the other hand, I find a book named Elementary Convexity with Optimization,https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-99-1652-8,  In the proof of  Theorem 3.6 If $C$ is closed convex and $x^* \in \partial C$, then there exists a hyperplane $H$ passing through $x^$ such that $C \subset L_H$ and $\operatorname{int}(\mathrm{C}) \subset \operatorname{int}\left(\mathrm{L}_{\mathrm{H}}\right)$.
Proof Let $x_n \notin C, n \geq 1$, such that $x_n \rightarrow x^$.    It indicates such a sequence does exist, but, I do not know why?

The original question has notation $x (y)$ which makes it hard to read. Also in your comment the proof relies on $x_n$ not in the set, but in your question you're asking about a closure and you want $x^*$ to be on the boundary. These are two different topics.

thanks a lot.  Suppose $X$ is a nonempty convex subset of $R^n,  $  and $y$ is a boundary of $X$, then  there a sequence $\left{x_n\right}$ converging to $ y $ such that for all $n, x_n \notin \bar{X}$, the closure of $X$,  since the boundary of $X$ and the boundary of    $\bar{X}$ are equal.
